# Vim using <c-6> to switch alternative file is not functional on Mac terminal

Tags: vim

Vim using `<c-6>` to switch alternative file is not functional on Mac terminal while MacVim works.

The current version of Vim is 7.3.

Comment: Use another terminal emulator: `<c-6>` works fine in [iTerm](http://www.iterm2.com/)

Answer (score 3):

To switch to the alternate file you can use control-shift-6 (`<C-^>`) or `:e #`. Both of these work in the Terminal.

Take a look at `:h CTRL-^`

Comment: control-**shift**-6(<C-^>) does work. I wonder why <c-6> don't work on Mac's terminal while others linux terminals support this feature. Another key stroke (shift) is not cool.

Comment: I have remaped it in `.vimrc` : 
`nn <Leader><Leader> <c-^>`

Comment: this does not work on macbook pro 13 inch 2017

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to map `<C-#>` in terminal mode. It's a limitation of terminals that they can't handle most <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key combinations. The only ones that work are <kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and just a couple others. Similarly, you can't detect combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>; they just come through as `<C-a>`.

You'll either have to remap the key to something else, or configure your terminal emulator to send a different key combination when you press that. Either way, you'd have to configure your Vim to accept something other than `<C-6>` when using a terminal.

Comment: Kelly is talking about a built in feature to vim. This does work in terminal vim using `<C-^>`